# Apply and display mean filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I ran this code but for some reason the output is a white screen with a black right border. Does anyone know why that happens ?

```
image=imread('lena.jpg');
image=rgb2gray(image);
[rows,cols]=size(image);
paddedimage=padarray(image,[1 1]);
newimage=zeros(rows,cols);
tot=0;
for i=2:(rows-1)

   for j=2:(cols-1)
    for i1=i-1:i+1
        for j1=j-1:j+1
            jk=image(i1,j1);
            tot=tot+jk;
        end

    end
    tot=tot/9;
    newimage(i-1,j-1)=tot;
   end
    tot=0;
end

imshow(newimage);
```

Comment: Check the datatype of `newimage` before using `imshow`. It must either be `uint8` and range from `0` - `255` (integers only) or be of type `double` and range from `0` - `1`.

Comment: Also, any reason you aren't just using `conv2` for this? At least use it to check yourself

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Matlab which **display range** to use. You can let it choose automatically by using `imshow(newimage, []);`.
Output for the builtin demo image office_1.jpg:

```
imshow(newimage);
```

[image]

```
imshow(newimage, []);
```

[image]